# Wifi and Bluetooth not working on Acer Nitro 5 AN515-45-R715 clean install of 21.04 and 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 21.04, mediatek

I installed first Ubuntu 20.04 and later tried Ubuntu 21.04. Both times, no wifi adapter were found and Bluetooth wasn't working either. Same story after updating packages.
Wifi works on Windows. SecureBoot disabled.

To my understanding the wifi card is a Mediatek mt7961

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7961]
```

No drivers for it:

```
inxi -nz

Network:
  Device-1: Realtek driver: r8169 
  IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: MEDIATEK driver: N/A
```

Kernel:

```
uname -a
Linux ****-Nitro-AN515-45 5.11.0-18-generic
```

Anything I could do to get the wifi working? I mainly work with Ubuntu and would like to keep the laptop.

**EDIT**
After upgrading the kernel to 5.12.9, the Wifi is working. However, Bluetooth still doesn't.

Trying to also fix Bluetooth

```
lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b64f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD User Facing
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c051 Logitech, Inc. G3 (MX518) Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:3802 Lite-On Technology Corp. Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


sudo dmesg | grep -i blue

[    1.967037] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    1.967076] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    1.967082] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    1.967084] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    1.967088] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.245128] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.245130] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.245133] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://medium.com/@pjbgf/installing-ubuntu-on-the-latest-asus-rog-g15-36487ecea862

Comment: Thanks, after upgrading the kernel to 5.12.9, the Wifi is working. However, Bluetooth still doesn't.

Comment: Please post: `lsusb` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: Posted in edit.

Comment: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/640544/problems-with-acer-nitro-5-an515-45-r715-in-ubuntu-21-04/p1?new=1

Answer (score -1):

Installing latest linux kernel (5.15) solved the problem for me.