# Asus TUF F15 stubbornly "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"

Tags: wireless, asus

Trying to get Ubuntu started on an Asus TUF F15 laptop... I've been reading what feels like hundreds of webpages and SE questions and *none of the solutions I have read has worked* despite seeming to be the exact same situation!

I've installed 20 LTS and 21 as well as Linux Mint. Nothing's worked!

I'm not well-versed in drivers et cetera so I'm extra confused and in the dark. If anybody could at least help me figure out what the issue *is*... is there some established bug report my hours of Googling hasn't got me to, or is something WIP, or...

Any help or at least explanation would be appreciated.

Asked command outputs:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04

$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:208f]
```

Comment: First, let's see what is currently installed. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsb_release -d` Now, let's identify your exact wireless device: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 done. Hopefully this info is helpful

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344604/wifi-and-bluetooth-not-working-on-acer-nitro-5-an515-45-r715-clean-install-of-21 You have the exact same device and require the 5.12.9 or later kernel. Please advise if you need a step-by-step.

Comment: @chili555 is https://medium.com/@pjbgf/installing-ubuntu-on-the-latest-asus-rog-g15-36487ecea862 the link to follow from there?

Comment: "Phwoarh, that was a palava", to be as unlike me as possible. Thanks, that worked. At last!! Water helps.

Answer (score 2):

Following two links from @chilli555's comment got me the solution for this case!!
Hopefully if you happen to be in this situation and nothing else has worked this *will* be the one.

It's installing an updated kernel.

```
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12.5/amd64/linux-headers-5.12.5-051205-generic_5.12.5-051205.202105190541_amd64.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12.5/amd64/linux-headers-5.12.5-051205_5.12.5-051205.202105190541_all.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12.5/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.12.5-051205-generic_5.12.5-051205.202105190541_amd64.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12.5/amd64/linux-modules-5.12.5-051205-generic_5.12.5-051205.202105190541_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

This downloads a bunch of packages and then installs all of them at once. Thanks again to @chilli555.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working!

Comment: Does touchpad work for you?

Comment: It does indeed. The toggle button on the keyboard doesn't, but settings does it for me. Hope this adds to the useful information :-)

Comment: @Tachytaenius Which kernel version are you using? For me, its not even detected, neither in Settings nor in xinput. Can you share the output of `xinput`? Here is my question with details in case you are interested https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352620/touchpad-not-working-on-asus-tuf-f15-2021-edition

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The kernel version I am using now is the one I downloaded as per chili555's answer, and the one(s) I started with is what came with the ISO, surely. It's been detected every time. Here is the output you asked for: https://hastebin.com/owucivonuy.txt
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Tachytaenius for your response. Tried that kernel as well but it got stuck at the Kubuntu logo. Then tried by going in recovery mode and kubuntu loaded but touchpad still doesn't detect.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to update the kernel using apt repositories. This worked for me after rebooting.

```bsh
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

Answer (score 0):

It was working fine with my system(Assus tuf f15). Suddenly wifi option got disappeared.

Tried almost everything.
This worked for me

```
1. enable secure boot in bios ( you can google this)
2. And update the kenal- 
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```