# WIFI adapter not found. Mediatek

Tags: wireless, adapter

Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Ethernen connection work. The wifi icon is not displayed on top, bluetooth is also turned off, but it is not clear how to turn it on? In wifi, he writes "The network adapter was not found" I ask you to help, i have already tried a bunch of options from the internet. Output lspci -knn | grep Net -A3: Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7961]
Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:5413] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:1100]
I am ready to provide all the necessary information, for you help me, but what kind?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: At least Ubuntu 20.04 with the 5.15 kernel in order for those wifi to work

Comment: @Jeremy31 When I installed ubuntu 20, there was also no Wi-Fi, the problem was solved by switching to 22, but there does not see the laptop keyboard at all. I just don't know what to do anymore

Comment: Possible to use 22.04 and USB keyboard, then you could get help with the other keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Check the BIOS setting. maybe your devices disabled.

If it is a laptop, check if the airplane mode on.

If you tell us some details about the hardware, maybe it will be easier.

reg
HBtools

Comment: ASUS TUF GAMING A15, i didnt find anything related to wifi in the bios, except for the network stack configuration, but everything is turned off there. The airplane is turned off.

Comment: Drivers installed?

Comment: this sound relevant, just a newer version of ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353477/asus-tuf-f15-stubbornly-no-wi-fi-adapter-found

Comment: I entered the commands that helped the person in that thread, but nothing happened. Some error message appeared at the top, but when I enter sudo apt-get -f I get "The command line parameter "f" [of -f] is not understandable in combination with other parameters." I didn't download any drivers, just booted ubuntu from a flash drive.

Comment: Probably the ubuntu live do not contains any drivers for your ASUS laptop.

Comment: If you would like to try linux, you can install linux on windows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Comment: I don't quite understand where I can get these drivers, could you tell me?

Comment: You mentioned that "boot ubuntu from flash drive" I means that you did not installed the Ubuntu to the drive, and it is running from the flash drive.

Comment: I think drivers can be found here: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/mediatek

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386578/no-wifi-adapter-found-asus

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 22, now I can't log in, when I press any button in the window, with a password, the screen just freezes, but somehow, Wi-Fi is there, I realized it by clicking on the icons in the upper panel.

Comment: By the way, I could not log in to the system.

Comment: I was able to log in from the on-screen keyboard, but he doesn't see my keyboard

Comment: Sometimes, it need just couple of minutes, to linux get the driver installed.

Comment: why do you install Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS  ???